# Change background to random colors on click - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change my body's background color to a random color every time a nav-bar link is clicked.

I got it so that a random color gets changed the first time a link is clicked - but when a different link is clicked, nothing changes.

Any tips?

HTML:

```
    <div class="nav">
      <ul id="show">
        <li id="link1"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</li></a>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#about">About</li></a>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#email">Contact</li></a>
        <hr/>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

     var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey'];

     var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

     $('.nav a').click(function() {
         $('body').css('background-color', randColor);
     });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid. It’s supposed to be `<li><a>…</a></li>` and not `<li><a>…</li></a>`. And remove the `<hr/>` inside the `<ul>`. `<ul>`s and `<ol>`s can only have `<li>`s as child elements.

Comment: Based on your function I made this https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/EmYBBP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only generate one random number and keep using it, move it inside of the click method.

Answer (score 1):

In each click you need to find a new random color, in your case the `randColor` variable is updated only once on the dom ready, in the click handle the same value is used all the time.

```js
$(function() {

  var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey'],
    color;

  $('.nav a').click(function() {
    var randColor;
    do {
      randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    } while (color == randColor);
    $('body').css('background-color', randColor);
    color = randColor;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="show">
    <li id="link1"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="link3"><a href="#email">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
</div>
```